# How to post a photo from my device to a friend's timeline with android sdk

Tags: post, photo, timeline, facebook-android-sdk

I know that after removing ability to post to friends walls via Graph API, we should invoke the feed dialog. But the feed dialog could not meet my requirement. I want to post a photo, which is on the SD card, to a friend's timeline/wall, just like a user could do with the Facebook.apk

My question is whether we could implement this feature with facebook-android-sdk and if we could, how to(which class/method)?